# Ilmerge causing dll's to open during build

Tags: visual-studio, dll, ilmerge

I am using ILMerge as a post build event to combine some dll's into a single dll. It is working and combining the dll's but have this weird issue. As the project builds, the dll's are opened (only external dll's, not project dll's)! And the build wont only progress when I close the application that opens the dll, in this case I have set reflector as the default application for opening dll's. The post build event command I am using is:

```
"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\External\Tools\ILMerge\2.10.0\ILMerge" /out:"$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Combined.dll" "$(TargetPath)"  
"$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Core.dll" 
"$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Resolver.dll" 
"$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)AjaxMin.dll" 
"$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.dll" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)EcmaScript.NET.modified.dll"
```

Anyone have issues with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hehe, kinda funny.  Remove the line breaks between the DLL names.  I'll edit your post to make them obvious.

With a DLL on a single line, it is interpreted as a build command instead of an argument to ILMerge.  It invokes the default action for a .dll file, which in your case is "open in Reflector".

Comment: Jee thats a weird one! Have put them all on one line and it works. Thanks!

Comment: I made the change that you suggested and it solves the opening of files with refractor issue. But now I am getting an error "exited with code 1". Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with this question anymore.  Please start another one, don't forget to document it properly.